# Flutter Doctor cannot find Android SDK

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

Today I started learning flutter for my mobile application and I followed every step for flutter installation but my flutter doctor can't find Android SDK.

When I type flutter doctor it shows me this:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.295], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\i5 4570\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\aapt.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] VS Code (version 1.38.0)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I tried everything, I made a new path, ANDROID_HOME, I did `flutter config --android-sdk "C:\Users\i5 4570\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"` but nothing happen...
Please help

Comment: Try with a different user that doesn't have a space in the username.

Comment: Does the following path exists : `C:\Users\i5 4570\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\aapt.` ? If no, then you need to download the android sdk version 29.

Comment: I don't see aapt. anywhere ?